# jQuery plugin Validate: onfocusin doesn't works

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins, validation

In this famous jQuery plugin called Validate there's an option called 'onfocusout'. But I want to use another called 'onfocusin' which is not documented BUT exists inside the code AND the plugin's author cited it on a reply.

The code I've been trying:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").validate({
     onsubmit: false,
     onkeyup: false, 
     onfocusin: true,
     onfocusout: false,
     rules: {
      nome: {
       required: true,
       minlength: 5
      }
     }
    })
   })
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form action="tutorial.php" method="post" enctype="text/plain" >
   <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" />
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
 </body>
```

And FireBug shows this error message when I 'focusin' the input:

```
validator.settings[eventType].call is not a function [Stop on this error] 
validator.settings[eventType] && v...eventType].call(validator, this[0] ); 
jquery...date.js (line 305)
```

Now, the golden question: How can this be fixed?

Links:

**Validate plugin:**

bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

**Validate documentation, options page:**

docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions

**Validate plugin code:**

ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.js

**Validate's author reply on abouth onfocusin:**

groups.google.com/group/jquery-en/browse_thread/thread/652418e93c9618f1?pli=1

Comment: what do you want to do with it? as you can see in the code, it's a function..using `false` will overwrite it (disable the effect), otherwise you have to define a function with what you want to do.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of onfocusin: true, use this:

```
onfocusin: function(element) { $(element).valid(); }
```

I've had the same issue with this error 
`validator.settings[eventType] && ...eventType].call(validator, this[0] );`

If you want to use onfocusout use the same code:

```
onfocusout: function(element) { $(element).valid(); }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use "true" (a bool value) as a value of onsubmit, onkeyup, onfocusin and onfocusout parameters. By default these are functions (and events are on). If you want to turn off this events, set values to "false" or "undefined" (without ").
To understand validation plugin, look through the source code. The documentation is not complete.
v1.9.